# HTML Form Submit does not open new site/doesn't open a site at all

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

after several hours looking for answer, I still haven't found a solution for my problem. I have a very basic form with some checkbox inputs. But the Submit Button doesn't open the php Script for processing the data.

Here's the form:

```
<form name="request" action="request.php" method="get">

                <h2 id="sum">5.99€</h2>
                <h6>Per Month</h6>
                <input type="hidden" name="hide">
                <!--The Hidden Input is there for testing purposes-->
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
```

And here's the full code of the section:

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Ordering Form</h2>
        <p class="text-muted">Choose some web essentials and add them to your plan
        <br><a class="page-scroll">Get to know the essentials</a></p><br>
        <form name="request" action="request.php" method="get">


            <h2 id="sum">5.99€</h2>
            <h6>Per Month</h6>
            <input type="hidden" name="hide">
            <!--The Hidden Input is there for testing purposes-->
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //Some JavaScript which doesn't have anything to do with the form
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

When i click the submit button its just doesn't do anything. No Error message, no 404, no PHP error.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: ok and the PHP that goes with this? No PHP error; that's because you're not checking for them and I have my doubts as to what's "not" happening.

Comment: Show your request.php file.

Comment: Are you sure there is no preventDefault in your JS related to the submit?

Comment: Is there code somewhere else on this page disabling the submit button?

Comment: Do you know if your browser sends this page at all? When I copy-paste your form, it works and redirects me to `request.php?hide=`

Comment: Over 10 minutes into this and no word from you, nor any related PHP code added, and you're expecting a magical answer to appear? *Wish*. I moved on, good luck with that.

Comment: Your code as shown above works fine so you either have a js script stopping the submit or some other code causing an error: http://jsfiddle.net/wmm05kvg/

Comment: Thanks for the hint with JS blocking the submit. Exactly that was the case because i used a code snippet from the web on another page of the site which blocks the submit and I inserted the script on every page (cause ctrl + c). From now on I will go back to coding everthing by myself. But thanks for the great help!